# Mysql server doesn't start at boot on Ubuntu 10.04LTS VPS

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-10.04, init.d

I did a apt-get update & installed few updates on my server which runs 10.04LTS. But this has broken mysql. it doesn't start at boot. I tried to manually start it using the following commands:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
Rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the service(8)
utility, e.g. service mysql restart

Since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an
Upstart job, you may also use the restart(8) utility, e.g. restart mysql
start: Job failed to start


$ sudo service mysql start
start: Job failed to start

$ service mysql start
start: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.5" (uid=1001 pid=1796 comm="start) interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Start" error name="(unset)" requested_reply=0 destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="init"))


$ restart mysql
restart: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.10" (uid=1001 pid=2014 comm="restart) interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Restart" error name="(unset)" requested_reply=0 destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="init"))
```

here is my [/etc/init/mysql.conf file for service](http://paste.ubuntu.com/977387/), [mysql error log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/978221/) & [/etc/mysql/my.cnf](http://paste.ubuntu.com/977644/). Currently, I have run `sudo mysqld &` only then, my server starts accepting connections but it causes problem as It has to be done after every reboot.

Please let me know how to I fix this.

Comment: Please provide the MySQL error log.

Comment: [mysql error log](http://paste.ubuntu.com/978221/)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've got a full disk?

```
120507 21:12:06 [ERROR] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Disk is full writing './gaurishs_gslive/wp_redirection_logs.MYD' (Errcode: 122). Waiting for someone to free space... (Expect up to 60 secs delay for server to continue after freeing disk space)
```

The service is definitely starting despite that, though; your starts may be failing because the service is already running.